# insert array values to range of cells in excel with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, excel, foreach

currently the loop I'm running returns the values I need but I can't figure out how to get the returned array values inserted into a range of cells. continually getting this error:

message: "The number of rows or columns in the input array doesn't match the size or dimensions of the range."

```
let allValues =  sheetValuesRange.values;    
            
allValues.forEach(function(row, index){
  let emptyArray = [];
  let att = 1;
  if (row[3] > 0) {
    emptyArray.push(row[65], (att), row[3]);
  }
  
  let upc3ValueRange = sheet.getRange("A90:A132");

  upc3ValueRange.values = emptyArray;        
})
```

Comment: Is this in node.js? Is it using a particular excel library?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two dimensional array. For example, to set values 1, 2, 3 in `A90:A92`, your array will be `[[1],[2],[3]]`.